# Convert linear division function into logarithimic

Tags: loops, math, division

Im not sure if I am using the correct mathematical terminology but here goes...

I currently have a function that divides a number equally by another number.

```
function factorIt(numPieces, totalSize) {
    return totalSize / numPieces;
}
```

This returns a linear/even division. What I need to do is return values that form an uneven/exponential/logarithmic set.

For example, running the function above 10 times, on the values 500 and 10 would return 50 ten times, because 500 divided by 10 is 50. But I need it to return a something more like:

```
1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 30, 60, 100, 150, 200 // All should add up to input value
```

These 10 values actually add up to 578, but the function needs it to add up to the input value of 500. This is as far as Ive currently got..

```
var output = '';
for (var i = 1; i<11; i++) {
    output += factorIt(i, 10, 500) + '<br>';
}
function factorIt(i, numPieces, totalSize) {
    var factor = 5;
    return totalSize / numPieces / i * factor; // Err...something like this... :-S
}
```

The ultimate objective of this function is to plot bitmaps over a two dimensional space with ever-decreasing space between them, in order to create an illusion of 3d receding perspective.

Does anyone know of the formula that I need for this? I can't seem to wrap my head around it...

Comment: From `1` to `10` base `10` logarithm goes from `0` to `1`.  Divide that interval by `5` (or whatever) to get 5 evenly spaced (in logarithmic scale) intervals `0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1`, now take antilogarithms.  Adjust the numbers to suit your application.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Thanks for your reply. Sorry, I am dumb, can you show that in a formula?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark With your approach you cannot guarantee that the numbers will sum up to the desired total value (in fact they most certainly will not ...)

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't specify exactly how to get the sequence "1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 30, 60, ...". Also you do no specify if you need the values to be integers.

If you want a "quasi-exponential" sequence which adds up to the given total, you could use succesive division by some fixed factor like:

```
var current = 500;
while (current > 0) {
  var new = ceil(current / 2);
  output = new + '<br>' + output;
  current = current - new;
}
```

this would generate "1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 31, 63, 125, 250" which sum up to 500. `ceil` is the ceiling function, i.e. the biggest integer greater or equal its argument (always "rounding up"). You could also use a different factor to produce shorter sequences (smaller factor) or longer ones.

Note that the loop produces the values in revesed order, i.e. starting with the biggest value. Also this approach might produce duplicate values of `1` at the beginning of the sequence (if starting with  any power of 2...)

Also, this approach doesn't let you specify the *number* of elements in the sequence. If you want to have fixed-size sequences, you could try to compute the factor by something similar to

```
f = exp(ln(total)/n)
```

But then again, if you only operate on integer values, this factor might need to be modified to get the correct result.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The "1,2,5,10,20" sequence I wrote down is arbitrary really. Its just to show that the division should be done exponentially. I tried to run the "while" loop you suggested after making some modifications but couldn't get it to work as I wanted, my bad really. But the concept helped. I finally managed to get it working after some tinkering about. I've put it up here in all its "Sonic the Hedgehog" glory if you or anyone else is interested. Cheers! http://jsfiddle.net/ovq5xrx0/